# Calling constructor of class member when using malloc

Tags: c++

The following code breaks due to the constructor of std::string never being called, as the call to malloc seemingly doesn't call the constructors of the class members.

How can I call the constructor for the std::string without using new? Or do I have to use placement new on the entire struct after memory for it has been allocated?

```
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    std::string value;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* cls = (MyClass*)malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
    cls->value = "hello";

    system("pause");
}
```

Edit:

After reading the comments, I would like to know if the following code will work as expected? Not sure if any destructor needs to be call other than the one for the overall class.

```
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    std::string value;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* cls = (MyClass*)malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
    cls = new(cls) MyClass;
    cls->value = "hello";

    cls->~MyClass();
    free(cls);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221604/discussion-on-question-by-gary-allen-calling-constructor-of-class-member-when-us).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`malloc` is a C function, and has no knowledge of classes, constructors, etc.

If you are dead-set on using this, you are going to *have to* always call placement `new` on each object (note: this requires including the header `<new>`), and also manually calling the destructor *before* deallocating. You will also need to store the pointer that is returned from placement `new` in order to avoid undefined behavior (as this is technically the only pointer that points to the start of the object's lifetime).

As you have in your edit, it will look something like:

```cpp
auto cls = static_cast<MyClass*>(std::malloc(sizeof(MyClass)));
cls = new(cls) MyClass(/* any arguments here ... */);
cls->value = "hello";

cls->~MyClass();
std::free(cls);
```

However, be aware that by using `malloc` you actually introduce other issues with respect to *exception safety*. If your placement-`new` call throws an exception, the memory allocated by `std::malloc` will *leak* -- which is bad. You also wouldn't want placement `new` to operate on `nullptr` if `malloc` returns null, and would need to convey this error -- perhaps through an exception.  You will probably want to wrap this into a helper that will ensure these conditions can't happen:

```cpp
#include <new>     // placement-new, std::bad_alloc
#include <utility> // std::forward
#include <cstdlib> // std::malloc, std::free

template <typename T, typename...Args>
T* make(Args&&...args)
{
    auto* p = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(sizeof(T)));

    // Placement new can't operate on nullptr
    if (p == nullptr) {
        // alternatively, this could be 'return nullptr' if not using exceptions
        throw std::bad_alloc{}; 
    }

    try {
        p = new (p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch (...) {
        std::free(p);
        throw; // rethrow the exception here
    }
    return p;
};
```

Similarly, you will likely want to have a way to destroy objects while deallocating them, so that resources aren't leaked:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void dispose(T* p)
{
    p->~T();
    std::free(p);
}
```

Using these utilities, the above example now becomes:

```cpp
auto cls = make<MyClass>(/* any arguments here ... */);
cls->value = "hello";

dispose(cls);
```

---

If this seems like an awful lot of boilerplate, this is because this is exactly what `new` and `delete` already does for you. If you can, you will be much better off using these facilities when dealing with C++ types. This also allows you to continue using other RAII-wrappers like smart pointers easily without having to manually specify allocators (`shared_ptr`) or deleters (`unique_ptr`).

There really isn't a good reason IMO to prevent using `new` and `delete` in favor of `malloc`/`free` when working with C++ code. If you have a library that exposes a C-only interface but is implemented *in* C++ code -- it would actually be better for you to internalize the allocations and switch to `new` and `delete` rather than using `malloc` and `free` so you can save yourself the hassle.<sup>1</sup>

One other thing to be aware of is that if the types allocated in your system ever have a custom alignment via `alignas` that exceeds `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, using `std::malloc` will be *undefined behavior* because it will be unable to satisfy the alignment requirements. This is another thing that `new`/`delete` would take care of for you.

---

<sup>1</sup> If your "mixed C++/C" code is exposing a C interface at some point, it would be much cleaner for you to use `new` and `delete` rather than `malloc`, and to simply expose the creation/deletion functions on your API explicitly. For example:

```cpp
// C header:

extern "C" 
my_class* make_my_class(void);

extern "C"
void dispose_my_class(my_class* p);

// C++ implementation:

extern "C"
my_class* make_my_class(void)
{
    return new my_class{ ... };
}

extern "C"
void dispose_my_class(my_class* p)
{
    delete p;
}
```

This is generally the approach taken for C/C++ interop.

Comment: I wonder, does the standard guarantee that the pointer returned by placement `new` points to the same memory address as the one returned by `malloc` here? Or is there some (theoretical) possibility where alignment would cause these two pointers to point to different memory addresses (which could then break the call to `free`)?

Comment: I misread your comment to be `new`/`delete` not placement `new`... Deleted my original response. Placement `new` is [guaranteed to return its input](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/new.delete.placement#2). Placement `new` effectively is a no-op function that primarily exists so that a "`new` expression" may be used in C++ to start the lifetime of an object (since all dynamic object's lifetimes begin with `new`)

Comment: Perhaps `std::aligned_alloc` can help with the last part in the answer (if c++17 is used that is)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was thinking that too, but didn't add this detail since OP mentions mandating `malloc`/`free` explicitly... There are plenty of better options that are better than using `malloc` for this particular problem (e.g. just cave and use `new`/`delete`)